# Parsing table for a link

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been able to isolate a row in a html table using Beautiful Soup in Python 2.7.  Been a learning experience, but happy to get that far.  Unfortunately I'm a bit stuck on this next bit.

I need to get the link that follows the **"Select document Remittance Report I format XLS"** input.  As this can change order of appearance, it needs to be dynamic.  I'm not sure how to find that input and then grab the link that follows it.

I've been trying some findAll and nextSibling methods but my inexperience with python and beautiful soup is holding me back.  The BeautifulSoup documentation is great but going a bit over my head.

---

```
<tr class="odd">
 <td header="c1">
  Report Download
 </td>
 <td header="c2">
  <input aria-label="Select Report format PDF" id="documentChkBx0" name="documentChkBx" type="checkbox" value="5446"/>
  <a href="/a/document.html?key=5446">
   <img alt="Portable Document Format" src="/img/icons/icon_PDF.gif">
   </img>
  </a>
  <input aria-label="Select Report format XLS" id="documentChkBx1" name="documentChkBx" type="checkbox" value="5447"/>
  <a href="/a/document.html?key=5447">
   <img alt="Excel Spreadsheet Format" src="/img/icons/icon_XLS.gif">
   </img>
  </a>
 </td>
 <td header="c4">
  04/27/2015
 </td>
 <td header="c5">
  05/26/2015
 </td>
 <td header="c6">
  05/26/2015 10:00AM EDT
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any "Select document Remittance Report I format XLS" string anywhere in that HTML, so I don't know how you're going to find the link after it.

Comment: What from the html you have provided do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the `input` by checking `aria-label` attribute and get the [following `a` sibling element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
label = soup.find("input", {"aria-label": "Select Report format XLS"})
link = label.find_next_sibling("a", href=True)["href"]
```

Comment: Alecxe, this worked perfectly.  Thank you!  


Now I have one modification I'd like to make... I'd like to search the "aria-label" value for two values.  Essentially, sometimes I need to find something other than "Report" and sometimes it is a different format than "XLS".  

So i need code (regex presuambly) that will search for a given name (in place of Report) and a given type (in place of XLS)  

This is what I've tried but it's not working:  
label = row.find("input", {"aria-label": re.compile("\b" + report_name + ".*\b" + report_type + ".*")})

Comment: @PegLegPete good, could you please elaborate it into a separate question so that more people would have a change to help you? Thanks.

Comment: I opened a new question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240843/trying-to-use-beautiful-soup-python-to-find-2-partial-matches-in-an-attribute